# How to capture WOL packets?

Tags: tcpdump, wireshark, wake-on-lan

I used

```
sudo tcpdump -v -i eth0 ether proto 0x0842 or udp port 9
```

but didn't see anything when `WakeMeOnLan` from `NirSoft` wakes the computer.

---

The same with `Wireshark`

[image]

Comment: Target computer was turned off and can't execute any code. Source computer was running both `WakeOnLan` and `wireshark`

Answer (score 6):

With this command you can reduce the output from the [tcpdump](/questions/tagged/tcpdump) to just the [mac-address](/questions/tagged/mac-address) that was attempted to be woken:

```bsh
tcpdump -UlnXi eth0 ether proto 0x0842 or udp port 9 2>/dev/null |
sed -nE 's/^.*20:  (ffff|.... ....) (..)(..) (..)(..) (..)(..).*$/\2:\3:\4:\5:\6:\7/p'
```

This catches wakeups from [`etherwake`](https://pkgs.org/download/etherwake), [ethertype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType) [0x0842 (AMD magic packet format)](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/20213.pdf), and [`wakeonlan`](https://pkgs.org/download/wakeonlan)([UDP:9](https://wiki.wireshark.org/WakeOnLAN)), but requires the interface run in [`promiscuous mode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode).

Output for this example is like:

```
44:55:33:11:56:66
11:22:33:66:56:af
11:be:33:ef:56:af
```

To test from a different computer with either of e.g.:

```
wakeonlan 12:de:ad:be:ef:56
etherwake -i wlp2s0 -b 31:32:33:34:35:36
```

To catch only the ones coming via UDP (e.g. `wakeonlan` command), you can use this script that doesn't require promiscuous mode:

```bsh
nc -dknl -p 9 -u |
 stdbuf -o0 xxd -c 6 -p |
 stdbuf -o0 uniq |
 stdbuf -o0 grep -v 'ffffffffffff' |
 while read ; do
   echo ${REPLY:0:2}:${REPLY:2:2}:${REPLY:4:2}:${REPLY:6:2}:${REPLY:8:2}:${REPLY:10:2};
 done
```

Instead of the `while read ... echo blabla` you could launch other actions.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) has this to say about the structure of a Wake-on-LAN packet (emphasis mine):

> The magic packet is a broadcast frame containing anywhere within its payload 6 bytes of all 255 (FF FF FF FF FF FF in hexadecimal), followed by sixteen repetitions of the target computer's 48-bit MAC address, for a total of 102 bytes.
>
> Since the magic packet is only scanned for the string above, and not actually parsed by a full protocol stack, **it could be sent as any network- and transport-layer protocol**, although it is typically sent as a UDP datagram to port 0, 7 or 9, or directly over Ethernet as EtherType 0x0842.

So, your current capture filter is not guaranteed to catch all WOL packets. And [according to the documentation](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html), it seems the WakeMeOnLan application has multiple ways to send the WOL packet, so you might need to make a short unfiltered test capture to find out what kind of WOL packets the application is sending, and then tailor your filter accordingly.